# Molecular formula for 4-methyl-1-pentanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

According to Wikipedia 4-methyl-1-pentanol is $\ce{C_6H_{14}O}$.

But here is what I got, which is slightly different.

Methyl = Think of methyl group, which is $\ce{CH_3}$.

Pentanol = *Penta* means we have 5 carbons, *-ane* ending means we have $2n+2$ hydrogens, i.e. 12 hydrogens and *-ol* ending means we have a hydroxyl group $\ce{-OH}$.

So the molecular formula that I arrived at is: $\ce{CH_3C_5H_{12}O}$ = $\ce{C_6H_{15}O}$.

How did I end up with an extra hydrogen compared to Wikipedia answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the formula you arrived at is $\ce{CH3C5H12OH}$ = $\ce{C6H16O}$.  In any case, in your "2n+2" step, you need to reduce that number of hydrogens by 2.  One is eliminated where the methyl group is attached, and a second is eliminated where the $\ce{-OH}$ group is attached.  So removing 2 hydrogens from $\ce{C6H16O}$, gives you the desired $\ce{C6H14O}$.

Answer (score 1):

You’re applying the $2n +2$ method wrongly. You need to stupidly count *all* the carbons in a fully saturated molecule and take *that* number as $n$.

In your case this is:

- 5 because *pent*anol
- another 1 because methyl.

That gives you six carbons in total. $n = 6 \Rightarrow 2n + 2 = 14$

Alcoholic oxygens do not introduce unsaturation, so you can safely ignore the oxygen here.